# ng-class does not recognize in form validation

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm working on form validation using AngularJS. 
I have this field:

```
 <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-5">
                Sign up<i class="fa fa-diamond" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>


    <form class="sa-innate-form" name="myForm" novalidate>

        <label>Username</label>
        <div ng-class="{'is-invalid' : myForm.username.$invalid}">
            <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" class="form-control" required /> 
            <span class="requiredLabel" ng-show="myForm.username.$invalid">required field!</span>
        </div>
```

So using `ng-class`, when the `username` field will be blank that `div` tag will have `is-invalid` as class.

If I use in my `CSS`:

```
<style>
.is-invalid.form-control {
        border: 2px solid red;
}
</style>
```

the border of the input tag with name `username` should be red when the class is `is-invalid` but it does not work.

Comment: Can you post your form element? Does it have `name="myForm"`?

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed up with the CSS rule that you have applied. There should be space between two classes `.is-invalid` & `.form-control`(in CSS rule) as they are not situated on same element. If elements lies on same element then they don't have space in between them.

```
<style>
 .is-invalid .form-control {
     border: 2px solid red;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: @DistribuzioneGaussiana it should work, you shouldn't be remove `style` tag from your code, I removed `style` element for demonstration

Answer (score 2):

looks like problem is with CSS. should be space between two classes.

```
<style>
.is-invalid .form-control {
        border: 2px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not work for me. Borders are not red.